# Is it possible to avoid the time constraint when clearing the browser cache in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: php, google-chrome, plugins, browser-cache

I am doing some local PHP development and therefore i frequently need to clear the browser cache (I am using Chrome). This has previously been pretty straight forward either in the DevTools or via a plugin for convenience (I am using Cache Killer). However, in the current Chrome (Version 75.0.3770.80) there seems to be a time constraint no matter what I do. Neither the plugin nor Chrome itself seem to be able to bypass this constraint. That is, if I edit a PHP file and need to update the browser to let the changes take effect, I have to wait – say a minute – before updating will also clear the cache. This is frustrating, to put it mildly. Right clicking the reload button and selecting “Empty Cache and Hard Reload” does not bypass the time constraint. I would be grateful if someone knows how to bypass it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If Ctrl + F5 or Cmd + F5 (Mac) doesn't work out, what I do to clear the cash complety is to go over the settings in Chrome, search for cookies, under Site Configurations, Cookies and them a manually delete the cookie 127.0.0.1 or localhost. That will kill php session, so any saved value in session will be lost, as PHP use session cookies. If you really want to even clear everything, you can also go on the session defined folder and remove the session files stored there.

---

When i update a JavaScript file, it usually does not load right away with my new modification, so I usually have to open it on DevTools and do a ctrl + F5 on the file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Marcus. I am unable to perform the steps - I am on a Windows 7 machine. It also seems a bit cumbersome for an effective work routine. Actually, I wasn't aware that PHP uses session cookies, but clearing the cache (including PHP) has not been an issue before. Also, shouldn't a session cookie simply point to cached data files? If those files are deleted, they ought to be restored?

Comment: On WIndows press F12 to open devtools,  press F1 and under Network tick the box Disable cache.

Comment: @jeff, I have already ticked that box. Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: On Windows 7, Chrome latest version (for now), go over the 3 dots on the upper right conner, then settings, then go over site settings, then cookies, then go over see all cookies and site data, there you can search for a cookie and delete it. That will belo the cookies-session on PHP. I dude that a lot for test porpuses. As for JavaScript files, to force them to reload, you need to open the on DevTools (by pressing F12 on the Chrome), locate them on source tab, and with the mouse pointer over the file core, you have to do a Ctrl + F5

Comment: Thank you for the extra details @Marcus. I might use your suggestion for PHP development. I am not having any issues with JavaScript, though - maybe due to the plugin I use.

Comment: Sorry for some typos there. I hope you got what I meant